# Android Material TextInputLayout endIcon cuts off text in MaterialAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, material-components-android

I have some very short text input (like only 2 numeric characters) yet using the endIcon will hog half of my textview and will cut off and display ellipses. I cannot make the TextInputLayout wider so I how can I display the full 2 characters (or more) while using endIconDrawable?
[image]

```js
          <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_input_assessment"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ptx_down_arrow_android"
                app:endIconTint="@color/colorPtxDarkBlue">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/dropdownDay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/truenorg"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"
                    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPtxDarkBlue"
                    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a workaround, not a final solution.

You can reduce the padding between the text and `endIcon` by adding a negative value in `android:drawablePadding`.
Something like:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdownDay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="-12dp"
        ../>
```

[image]

A final note. You don't need to use `android:background="@drawable/text_input_assessment"` to have rounded corners. Just add `app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Rounded"` in the `TextInputLayout` with:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style
```

Comment: Using the negative value to reduce the padding worked for me! Sometimes these are the solutions we need to work with haha... thanks for the suggestion on using the style to round the corners as well!

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a style for it already

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

So, the above line will add the dropdown icon automatically. **I think you'll need to remove this line**

```
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ptx_down_arrow_android"
```

Maybe the above line is overlapping the default icon

**Then if you want to set tint to the drawable, just create a custom style**

```
<style name="CustomAutoCompleteLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/colorPtxDarkBlue</item>
</style>
```

And you add this two lines if you like

```
style="@style/CustomAutoCompleteLayout"

android:theme="@style/CustomAutoCompleteLayout"
```

Also i suggest that you remove this line and add it to the **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout** instead.

```
android:paddingTop="10dp"               
android:paddingBottom="10dp
```

Comment: Hi Chisom - I also explored using the default icon provided (removing the custom drawable as you suggested) and the default drop down icon provided still cuts off the text.  Something with ExposedDropdownMenu icon takes up a lot of real estate for some reason.  Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i created this just now after 2hours and it worked very fine for me..

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="button_textcolor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Don't worry about the constans e.g @color/colorPrimary. What matters is the parent theme.

> Remember to use this below as your parent theme for AppTheme in android_manifest.xml since you've added style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu to <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout else app crashes

```
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

**Then add this to styles.xml also**

```
<style name="AppTheme.MaterialTextInputExposed" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">@dimen/_2dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">@dimen/_6dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">@dimen/_6dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">@dimen/_6dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">@dimen/_6dp</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="button_textcolor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/spinner</item>
</style>
```

**You can now modify your activity_main.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/choose_admission_mode"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.MaterialTextInputExposed"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MaterialTextInputExposed"
                    app:hintEnabled="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/choose_faculty"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/choose_program">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sp" 

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> I Changed the below line but it's not necessary. You just need to be careful with the padding and remember @dimen/_6dp has value of 6dp and  @dimen/_2dp has value of 2dp

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
```

to

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
```